# How to Invokerepeat and destroy objects in Unity3D(5.1)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm trying to make a game with similar type of gameplay as crossyroads, like with infinity level generation/enemy generation. Everything seems to work fine with the ground and enemy generation in my code, and it works when I play. But I can't make the new generated enemies to repeat themselves. I've tried to put the "Invoke repeating function" in void Start, void Update and inside the for loop. But it doesn't work. It only sends out one enemy.

And then I have problem to refer/find the new created objects(plane/enemies) so I can destroy them when they are out of screen.

I must have structured the code in a wrong way, but I can't figure it out.

```
    public class levelGenerationScrip : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject greenPlane;
public GameObject bluePlane;
public GameObject brownPlane;
public GameObject testEnemy;

int firstRand;
int secondRand;
int distPlayer = 12 ;
int enemyDist= 7;

Vector3 intPos = new Vector3 (0,0,0);
Vector3 enemyPos = new Vector3 (0,0,0);
Vector3 enemyPos2 = new Vector3 (0,0,0);

void Start () {

}

void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
    {
        firstRand = Random.Range(1,4);
        if(firstRand == 1)
        {
            secondRand = Random.Range(1,1);
            for(int i = 0; i < secondRand; i++)
            {
                intPos = new Vector3(-2.3f,0.5f,distPlayer);
                enemyPos = new Vector3 (7,1.51f,enemyDist);

                distPlayer += 1 ;
                enemyDist += 1;

                GameObject greenIns = Instantiate(greenPlane) as GameObject;
                greenIns.transform.position = intPos ;

                GameObject testEn = Instantiate (testEnemy) as GameObject;
                testEn.transform.position = enemyPos ;
                testEn.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce(new Vector3 (-350, 0, 0));
                //InvokeRepeating ("testEn",1,1.5f);
            }

        }
        if(firstRand == 2)
        {
            secondRand = Random.Range(1,1);
            for(int i = 0; i < secondRand; i++)
            {
                intPos = new Vector3(-2.3f,0.5f,distPlayer);
                enemyPos2 = new Vector3 (-11,1.51f,enemyDist);
                distPlayer += 1 ;
                enemyDist += 1;

                GameObject blueIns = Instantiate(bluePlane) as GameObject;
                blueIns.transform.position = intPos ;

                GameObject testEn = Instantiate (testEnemy) as GameObject;
                testEn.transform.position = enemyPos2 ;
                testEn.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce(new Vector3 (+350, 0, 0));
            }
        }
        if(firstRand == 3)
        {
            secondRand = Random.Range(1,1);
            for(int i = 0; i < secondRand; i++)
            {
                intPos = new Vector3(-2.3f,0.5f,distPlayer);
                enemyPos = new Vector3 (7,1.51f,enemyDist);

                distPlayer += 1 ;
                enemyDist += 1;


                GameObject brownIns = Instantiate(brownPlane) as GameObject;
                brownIns.transform.position = intPos ;

                GameObject testEn = Instantiate (testEnemy) as GameObject;
                testEn.transform.position = enemyPos2 ;
                testEn.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce(new Vector3 (+400, 0, 0));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

By "Unity" in your tag i take it you meant to put "Unity3d"

After instantiation of your gameobjects, shove them into a global list variable, now you can refer to them anytime you so please.

```
// global var
List<GameObject> objs = new List<GameObject>();

// inside function
GameObject blueIns = Instantiate(bluePlane) as GameObject;
objs.Add(blueIns);

GameObject testEn = Instantiate (testEnemy) as GameObject;
objs.Add(testEn);
```

And as for your InvokeRepeating problem, you havent posted your usage of it so i cannot tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Hi!  I want to continuosuly make enemies at that same position after I Instantiate them.. I´ve tried to make it with "InvokeRepeating ("testEn",1,1.5f);" but i guess it only works with a function..thnx for the help with the list.

Comment: Yea, you cant pass a gameobject into invoke it has no idea what you want to do with it.